# Notation measure theory: $d\mu(x)$

Tags: measure-theory, notation

Let $\mu$ be a measure on a measurable space $(S,\mathcal{A})$ if we have the integral  $\int_S f(x)d\mu(x)$ with $f$ a real valued function, what does $d\mu(x)$ mean? Why is the differential a function of x, what is the intuition here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's think back to the regular calculus integral: $\int f(x)\,dx$.  What does the $dx$ mean here?  Officially, $\int f(x) \,dx$ is the number you get when you take the infimum of the upper sums over all partitions (or the supremum of the lower sums over all partitions -- the sup and inf should be the same for the Riemann integral to exist).

The above definition is a technical definition; however, we can intuitively think of $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)\,dx$ as an infinite sum $\sum\limits_{\alpha_{i}} f(\alpha_{i})\cdot \Delta_{i}$, where $\alpha_{i}$'s represent all real numbers between $a$ and $b$, and $\Delta_{i}$ is the width of an infinitely thin rectangle **whose base contains the $x$-value $\alpha_{i}$**.  (So the intuition here is to partition the domain/$x$-values, and add up over all $x$-values.  This will be different in the Lebesgue integral below.)  Note that in this intuition, the infinite sum would be an *uncountable* sum, not the usual countable sum you learned about in Calculus.  We don't really have a way to sum up uncountably many items, so instead we take the supremum (or infimum).  So in the Riemann integral case, $dx$ is the length of the base of an infinitely thin rectangle containing $\alpha_{i}$ for each $x=\alpha_{i}$ in $[a,b]$.

In the two paragraphs above, I tried to highlight the actual technical definition, and then the intuition which motivates the definition.  In the same way, we can discuss $\int f(x)\,d\mu(x)$.  With the Lebesgue integral, if $f\geq 0$, the official definition of $\int f(x)\,d\mu(x)$ is the number you get when you take supremum of the the Lebesgue integrals of all nonnegative simple functions $s(x)$ sandwiched between $0$ and $f$, i.e., where $0 \leq s \leq f$.  The Lebesgue integral of the simple function $s(x) = \sum_{i} c_{i}\Bbb 1_{A_{i}}$ is $\int s(x)\,d\mu(x) = \sum_{i} c_{i}\Bbb \mu(A_{i})$.  So taking the supremum of these integrals over all simple functions sandwiched between $0$ and $f$ gives you a number which we define $\int f(x)\,d\mu(x)$ to be (for $f \geq 0$).

Intuitively, $\int f(x)\,d\mu(x)$ is also an uncountable sum.  However, instead of adding up terms over all possible values of $x$ as in the Riemann integral case, we add up over all possible values of the variable $y$ (where $y = f(x)$).  So let's say $y = f(x)$ will take output values in the interval $[c,d]$.  We want to add up terms that look like: $y_{i} \cdot \mu(\{x \mid f(x) = y_{i}\})$, i.e., possible value $y_{i}$ of $f$, multiplied by the size of the domain subset where $f$ will equal $y_{i}$.  So $\int f(x)\,d\mu(x) = \sum_{y_{i}} y_{i}\mu(\{x \mid f(x) = y_{i}\})$.  Of course, this is only intuition, since, again, we don't have a notion of uncountable sum in math.  So $d\mu(x)$, which is also often noted $\mu(dx)$, represents the measure of the set of $x$ such that $f(x)$ equals $y_{i}$.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am not sure this answer the question, even though it is a good explanation of integration. The symbol $d\mu$ in the question does not necessarily denote the Lebesgue measure. So, I think that the "right" answer is the one of Kavi Rama Murthy.

Comment: @giuseppenegro No where have I mentioned Lebesgue measure. $\mu$ can represent any measure. I think regardless of the measure, we can still refer to the new integral as the Lebesgue integral. $d\mu$ denotes the measure with respect to which you are integrating, whether it’s Lebesgue measure, counting measure, Hausdorff measure, etc. These are all different ways to measure the size of a set, and my answer above works equally the same with all of them.

Answer (score 3):

$\int_S f(x)d\mu(x)$ is just another notation for $\int_S f d\mu$. This notation is sometimes useful when there are several variable involved. For example $\int_S f(x,y) d\mu (x)$ denotes the integral of the function $g(x) =f(x,y)$ w.r.t. $\mu$ when $y$ is fixed.

Comment: Another common equivalent notation is $\mu(dx)$.